# Firebase new version getDownloadUrl in picasso not working

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
saveUrlToCategory(categoryIdSelect,taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl().toString(),textname, textdescription);
```

`getDownlaodUrl` is not working. I need to save this in a firebase database and than display it in picasso. How can I get this working?

Comment: Is not working, do you have an error or?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UploadTask uploadTask = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child(user.getUid()).child("avatar").child(avatarName)
                            .putFile(uri);
                    Task<Uri> urlTask = uploadTask.continueWithTask(new Continuation<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot, Task<Uri>>() {
                        @Override
                        public Task<Uri> then(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) throws Exception {
                            if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                                throw task.getException();
                            }

                            return FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child(user.getUid()).child("avatar").child(avatarName).getDownloadUrl();
                        }
                    }).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Uri>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task) {
                            if (task.isSuccessful()) {


                                Uri downloadUri = task.getResult();
                                String downloadUrl = downloadUri.toString();
                                childRef.child("avatar")
                                        .setValue(downloadurl);
                                     // Or in your case it is: 
                             saveUrlToCategory(categoryIdSelect,downloadUrl,textname, textdescription);


                            } else {
                                Log.e("FirebaseError:", "Error");
                            }
                        }
                    });
```

Comment: Can you please add some explanations so the OP can understand what this code is all about?

Comment: tried your code not working I've tried same code before i am unable to get download URL to display it on Picasso

Comment: Please put your full code then only it will be possible to understand what's happening.